# SSDT Schema Compare shows same objects to add and delete in destination

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio

When using schema compare, it shows the objects in dbo schema as objects to add in destination and same objects to delete as well. After inspecting the definitions, they appear to be the same. Why aren't they recognized as such? I would think if there are differences it will show them next to each other and fall under the Changes category. During the Build, it returns an unresolved reference to Schema [dbo] error. Anyone have this issue before?  [image: schema compare]

Comment: Check the file names/locations.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese the file names are the same as the actual name of the object.

Comment: Do you use git or other source control? If so, apply the changes and then look to see what changed on the local file system. Most of the time I have had this issue, there was something weird going on with the files or folder structure.

Comment: Do you have errors in your project when trying to build?